# Redirect .htaccess .php?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I´d like to do some redirects this for a new Wordpress website:

```
domain.com/index.php?cPath=24 --> domain.com/about/
```

My .htaccess (root) looks like:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?cPath=24 /about/
```

I get just this:

```
domain.com/?cPath=24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mod_rewrite` with a redirect flag to accomplish this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=24
RewriteRule ^ /about/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have now edited my answer to include what is known as a "query string discard", which completely gets rid of the parameters. This is achieved by adding an empty question mark at the end of the destination.